# How to replace a Exponential function with a series in a complex expression using sympy or MMA?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sympy

I have a function like this :

[The Funtion in MMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o8Uj.png)

the express for MMA code:

```
1/(-0.00001 + accT)^11 3.03226 (3.7499 - 8.57119 accT + 
   4.99983 accT^2 + 0.600048 accT^3 - 1.50004 accT^4 + 
   1. accT^5) (0.285697 + 0.0000119995 accT - 0.599976 accT^2 - 
   2.*10^-14 accT^3 + 1.5*10^-9 accT^4 - 0.00006 accT^5 + 
   1. accT^6) (-1. + E^(
   3/2 (1 - (1.56078 (-0.00001 + accT))/phVel)^2)) phVel^2
```

I want to integrate accT in (0,1).

I have try  lots of ways to integrate the function. Fox example,set the Lower limit of integration in 0.0000001 or split integral interval to every 0.01 then Multiply by the express,i.e,Rectangular method, loop i in [0.01,100]:
                                  express1+=0.01*express(i)
but all fail.

so I try to using series to expand  E^(3/2 (1 - (1.56078  ( -0.00001 + accT))/phVel)^2),and use the result replace Exponential function.

```
    import sympy as sy
    #like picture
    express = .....
    expressionSeries = sy.exp( 3/2 (1 - (1.56078 (-0.00001 +accT))/phVel)**2),
    expressionSeries = sy.series(expressionSeries,accT,0,5)
    expression = expression.subs(sy.exp( 3/2 (1 - (1.56078 (-0.00001 +accT))/phVel)**2),expressionSeries)
```

the code dosen't work. 
The integrate result should integrate(express)~phVel^7

Answer (score 0):

You have a factor of `1/(-0.00001 + accT)^11` and so when `accT==0.00001` it looks like you will have infinity.

You might try to find

```
Simplify[
  Limit[Integrate[yourfunction,{accT,0,a}],a->0.00001,Direction->"FromBelow"]+
  Limit[Integrate[yourfunction,{accT,a,1}],a->0.00001,Direction->"FromAbove"]
]
```

but that looks like it might be adding -infinity and infinity and the result of that can be anything.

Lots of things about this question and this response really worry me.